# set selected value for dropdown in table using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net

I'm adding a table row using jquery wit dropdownlist in it as follows -

```
$.each(data, function (i, item) {
$('#tableRM > tbody:last-child').append('<tr sn=' + item.SN + '>
<td>
<select name="RMLotName" class="form-control lotColumns">
<option value="">Select</option>
<option value="Lot1">Lot1</option>
<option value="Lot2">Lot2</option>
<option value="Lot3">Lot3</option>
</select>
</td>
    <td><input name="RMLotQty" type="text" disabled class="form-control lotColumns" value="' + item.LotQty + '" /></td>

</tr>)
    
    }
```

Now I want to select the default value for dropdownlist with `Name = #RMLotName`
I tried :-

```
$('#RMLotName').val("'" + item.LotName+"'");
```

and

```
$("#RMLotName option[value='" + item.LotName+"']").attr('selected', 'selected');
```

but it's not working. I've searched for a while and found some links like [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35262910/set-selected-value-for-dropdowns) [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46992714/set-dropdown-selected-value-after-loading-dropdown-values-in-jquery) and others but none of them are working.

Comment: `#RMLotName` is an id selector

Comment: Yes, It's Name of select.

Comment: `name` and `id` are different and so are their selectors. You do not have `id` on the select and since it is repeating there is no need for it either since `id` must be unique in  page.

Comment: Yes, but I'm using it for some other purpose in page.

Comment: No idea what that means but `$('#RMLotName')` is not going to work on the`<select>` shown since it has no `id`. Does my answer below help you?

Comment: Ok, I've got your point. commented below on answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider creating a jQuery object out of the row html before appending that object.

It allows you to use jQuery methods on that specific row. Then you need a better selector for the `<select>`

```
$.each(data, function (i, item) {

      let rowHtml = `<tr sn="${item.SN}"><td>
                <select name="RMLotName" class="form-control lotColumns">
                <option value="">Select</option>
                <option value="Lot1">Lot1</option>
                <option value="Lot2">Lot2</option>
                <option value="Lot3">Lot3</option>
                </select>
                </td>
                <td><input name="RMLotQty" type="text" disabled class="form-control lotColumns" value="${item.LotQty}" /></td>
            </tr>`;
      // create object from html string
      let $row = $(rowHtml)
      // set value of the select within this row instance
      $row.find('select.lotColumns').val(item.LotName);
      // append updated object to DOM
      $('#tableRM > tbody:last-child').append($row);

 });
```

Comment: Ok. The select value is selected. But the other values are coming as it is like ${item.SN}. I did $row.find('#RMSN').val(item.SN);

Comment: So you suggest that I remove the Name attribute and use class instead?

Comment: You can not repeat id in a page....think of them like an address. You can't send mail to an address that is used on multiple buildings. Also none of the elements shown have an `id="RMSN"` which is very different than `name="RMSN"`

Comment: removed the Name attribute and replaced with class. Same problem is there.

Comment: Show me the code used. A demo in jsfiddle or other sandbox site would be helpful. Not sure why following my example using a class doesn't work

Comment: Oh it's done. I was missing some small modifications. Thanks a lot for your help.